# Why does daterange function not exist?

Tags: c#, datetime, npgsql

I tried the below postgresql command in my C# (Net Core 2.2 + npgsql 4.0.6):

```
string _sql = "select * from user_branch_rotation where daterange(start_date, end_date,'[)') && daterange('2019-02-10','2020-05-11') and users_pid=4 and branch_pid=2"

var _q = await _conn.QueryAsync(_sql , new { });
```

but it returns

> "Function daterange(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without
>   time zone) does not exist"

note. I tried the above postgresql command on pgadmin and it works properly.

Has anybody experienced this?

Comment: could be that the function exists but it's being called it incorrectly - check params..?

Comment: Try executing that sell directly in postgress. Make sure you are calling the right db

Answer (score 0):

just want to share,

this problem resolved by using tsrange:

```
    select * from user_branch_rotation where (tsrange(start_date,end_date,'[]') 
    &&  (tsrange('2019-02-10','2020-05-11','[]') and users_pid=4 and branch_pid=2
```